# How to resolve "Connection refused" when executing bin/rails (spring) commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring-gem

I can execute `rails`-commands in production (FreeBSD 10) as long as **Spring is disabled**:

```
# DISABLE_SPRING=1 bin/rails runner -e production 'p "test"'
"test"

# script/rails runner -e production 'p "test"'
"test"
```

**With Spring**, the `rails`-command fails with the following error:

```
# bin/rails runner -e production 'p "test"' 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:20:in `initialize': Connection refused - "/tmp/spring/6e31dd16c1146fc209ac385f36aac9a1" (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:20:in `open'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:20:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:54:in `verify_server_version'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:25:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /s/usr-local/www/the_project/releases/20140724133941/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

So far, I verified that the according files in `/tmp/spring` exist as expected.

**What could be the cause of this error and how can I achieve a correctly working Spring?**

**UPDATE 1**

Here is an outline of several checks I did so far.

```
# ls -al /tmp/spring
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 proj     wheel   8 Jul 27 19:35 .
drwxrwxrwt  36 root     wheel  43 Jul 28 08:22 ..
srwxr-xr-x   1 proj     wheel   0 Jul 27 19:35 3004493e4fa38d91e78f82a2e74b4bc8
-rw-r--r--   1 proj     wheel   6 Jul 27 19:35 3004493e4fa38d91e78f82a2e74b4bc8.pid
srwxr-xr-x   1 proj     wheel   0 Jun 30 13:00 383a7b299457953fc0eda45a4eca65f8
-rw-r--r--   1 proj     wheel   5 Jun 30 13:00 383a7b299457953fc0eda45a4eca65f8.pid
srwxr-xr-x   1 proj     wheel   0 Jul 24 14:01 6e31dd16c1146fc209ac385f36aac9a1
-rw-r--r--   1 proj     wheel   6 Jul 24 14:01 6e31dd16c1146fc209ac385f36aac9a1.pid

# groups proj
proj wheel rvm

# bin/spring status
Spring is running:

25240 ruby: spring server | 20140727193408 | started 14 hours ago (ruby)
25245 ruby: spring app    | 20140727193408 | started 0 secs ago | production mode (ruby)

# fuser /tmp/spring/*
/tmp/spring/3004493e4fa38d91e78f82a2e74b4bc8:
/tmp/spring/3004493e4fa38d91e78f82a2e74b4bc8.pid: 25240wa
/tmp/spring/383a7b299457953fc0eda45a4eca65f8:
/tmp/spring/383a7b299457953fc0eda45a4eca65f8.pid:
/tmp/spring/6e31dd16c1146fc209ac385f36aac9a1:
/tmp/spring/6e31dd16c1146fc209ac385f36aac9a1.pid: 17260wa

# ps aux | grep -E '25240|17260'
proj        17260  0.0  0.1  79040  3544  -  IJ   Thu02PM 0:00.47 ruby: spring server | 20140724133941 | started 92 hours ago (ruby)
proj        25240  0.0  0.1  79040  3372  -  IJ    7:35PM 0:00.28 ruby: spring server | 20140727193408 | started 14 hours ago (ruby)

# head -n1 /tmp/spring.log     
[2014-07-28 10:16:40 +0000] [66008] [server] started on /tmp/spring/3004493e4fa38d91e78f82a2e74b4bc8

# tail /tmp/spring.log
[2014-07-28 10:18:00 +0000] [66008] [server] accepted client
[2014-07-28 10:18:00 +0000] [66008] [server] running command rails_runner
[2014-07-28 10:18:00 +0000] [66128] [application:production] got client
[2014-07-28 10:18:00 +0000] [66128] [application:production] forked 66370
[2014-07-28 10:18:00 +0000] [66008] [application_manager:production] got worker pid 66370
[2014-07-28 10:18:03 +0000] [66128] [application:production] 66370 exited with 0
```

Comment: What is process 17260 running for four days? Did you try to shut all servers down and restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by changing the users login shell to *bash* (before, it was set to *zsh*) and adding this *PATH* to ~/.profile: `PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/wrappers:$PATH`

To ensure only RVM's ruby is being used, I also forcefully removed the system ruby (1.9.3): `pkg remove -f ruby`

*(Note: Without the PATH setting mentioned above, this now causes the expected error `env: ruby: No such file or directory`)*

It appears a `killall ruby` was necessary in order for the changes to take effect.
Maybe a `bin/spring stop` would've been sufficient too.

Comment: Good to hear you sorted this out, had my fair share of ruby/rvm issues. You might as well award the bounty to my answer as those rep is gone anyways, thank you very much. :)

Comment: Would've been ok with me, but I've been away and only now I saw your comment. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on this, it seems the spring server can not be started or you are not allowed to connect to the socket:

- Check the permissions and ownership of the socket file and **the containing folder `/tmp/spring`**.
- Try to delete the socket file, change the folder permissions on `/tmp/spring` to `777` (just to rule this out as root cause) and restart the app / server. ["Connecting to the socket object requires read/write permission."](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix)
- Did you check that `spring/server` is actually running? The client tries to [boot the server if it is not running](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/48bea58a9633647a459cc68d0c9b13470f9c6af5/lib/spring/client/run.rb#L24)), but if that does not work, you get the `ECONNREFUSED`. Try to debug into the spring sources.
- Does `lsof | grep '/tmp/spring/6e31dd16c1146fc209ac385f36aac9a1'` give you anything if you think the server is running? What does `ps -ax | grep [process id]` say about the server process?
- What is the output of [`bin/spring status`](https://github.com/rails/spring#usage)?
- Try to [find out what spring is doing](https://github.com/rails/spring#troubleshooting) from the log file (look out for [`started on #{env.socket_name}`](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/c2c9fa3d4fc8ac8d9cb80dc5d8b670f54bd7f3a7/lib/spring/server.rb#L43) message).

Comment: Thanks for the hints, Wolfram. I had previously checked most of the things. I added "UPDATE 1" to the question. It contains answers to your suggestions. Note that user **proj** is in **wheel**.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question with the message `Error connecting to Spring server`.

The solution for me was as simple as:

```
spring stop
```

With that, my `db:migrate` task completed successfully.